# How to track user interaction when a dialog is shown?

Tags: android, timeout, user-interaction

I use Activity.onUserInteraction() in my application which triggers on any interaction (e.g. tapping the screen somewhere) even if it will not lead to action. Perfect for screen timeouts, etc.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    public void onUserInteraction()
    {
        idleTimer = 15;
    }
    ...
}
```

However, when I show a dialog (via AlertDialog.Builder) the above method won't be called anymore. I understand that it isn't my activity anymore, but how can I implement something similar when the dialog is active? I would like to track any activity, not just the ones result in action to manage (lower) brightness manually after a given length of user inactivity.

In case you need details about how the dialog is shown:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.number_picker, null);
    final NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker)view.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
    if (np == null)
        return;

    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage(title)
            .setView(view)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    MainActivity.onNumberPickerClose(code, np.getValue());
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

    MainActivity.SetupNumberPicker(np, from, to, defaultValue);

    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: I guess Its happening because dialog is another/sub activity. So you need to use main activity context in it to fetch touch events

Comment: Any idea how to "use main activity context"? Anyway, it's a little bit strange that onPause() is not called when the dialog is shown - if it's a different activity, shouldn't it be called?